# How to select all elements in a folder strean in my page?

Tags: php, html, css, image, stream

I'm trying to make a gallery with all the images from a folder stream in my site.

But, I just want to add the picture to the folder and automatically the picture will stream on my site.

In other word, in my code I want to say `"scr="ALL THE FOlDER"`

I want to use `HTML` attribute `<marquee>`.

Thank again.

Comment: Edit your question properly and you may get help. Please read [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Use php glob and iterate all results  http://php.net/manual/en/function.glob.php

Answer (score 0):

You can use [scandir](http://php.net/scandir)

```
$images = scandir('dir/');
foreach($images as $image) {
  //rest of the code
}
```

But since you want to search for specific file type i.e. image type you should use [glob](http://php.net/glob)

```
$images = glob('dir/*.{jpg,png,gif}', GLOB_BRACE);
foreach($images as $image) {
  //rest of the code
}
```